# tkinter execution dies after about 140 iterations with no error message (mem leak?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

My code dies after about 140+ iterations, and I don't know why. I guess memory leak is a possibility, but I couldn't find it. I also found out that changing some arithmetic constants can prolong the time until the crash.

I have a genetic algorithm that tries to find best (i.e. minimal steps) route from point A (`src`) to point B (`dst`).

I create a list of random chromosomes, where each chromosome has:

1. src + dst [always the same]
2. list of directions (random)

I then run the algorithm:

1. find best route and draw it (for visualization purposes)
2. Given a probability P - replace the chromosomes with cross-overs (i.e. pick 2, and take the "end" of one's directions, and replace the "end" of the second's)
3. Given probability Q - mutate (replace the next direction with a random direction)

This all goes well, and most of the times I do find a route (usually not the ideal one), but sometimes, when it searches for a long time (say, about 140+ iterations) it just crushes. No warning. No error.

How can I prevent that (a simple iteration limit can work, but I do want the algorithm to run for a long time [~2000+ iterations])?

I think the relevant parts of the code are:

1. `update` function inside GUI class
2. which calls to `cross_over`
3. When playing with the `update_fitness()` score values (changing `score -= (weight+1)*2000*(shift_x + shift_y)` to `score -= (weight+1)*2*(shift_x + shift_y)` it runs for a longer time. Could be some kind of an arithmetic overflow?

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from enum import Enum
from random import randint, sample
from copy import deepcopy
from time import sleep
from itertools import product


debug_flag = False

class Direction(Enum):
    Up      = 0
    Down    = 1
    Left    = 2
    Right   = 3

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.name)[0]

# A chromosome is a list of directions that should lead the way from src to dst.
# Each step in the chromosome is a direction (up, down, right ,left)
# The chromosome also keeps track of its route
class Chromosome:   
    def __init__(self, src = None, dst = None, length = 10, directions = None):
        self.MAX_SCORE = 1000000

        self.route = [src]
        if not directions:
            self.directions = [Direction(randint(0,3)) for i in range(length)]
        else:
            self.directions = directions
        self.src = src
        self.dst = dst
        self.fitness = self.MAX_SCORE

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.fitness)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__str__()

    def set_src(self, pixel):
        self.src = pixel

    def set_dst(self, pixel):
        self.dst = pixel

    def set_directions(self, ls):
        self.directions = ls

    def update_fitness(self):
        # Higher score - a better fitness
        score = self.MAX_SCORE - len(self.route)

        score += 4000*(len(set(self.route)) - len(self.route))  # penalize returning to the same cell
        score += (self.dst in self.route) * 500                 # bonus routes that get to dst

        for weight,cell in enumerate(self.route):
            shift_x = abs(cell[0] - self.dst[0])
            shift_y = abs(cell[1] - self.dst[1])
            score -= (weight+1)*2000*(shift_x + shift_y)        # penalize any wrong turn

        self.fitness = max(score, 0)

    def update(self, mutate_chance = 0.9):
        # mutate #
        self.mutate(chance = mutate_chance)

        # move according to direction
        last_cell = self.route[-1]

        try:
            direction = self.directions[len(self.route) - 1]
        except IndexError:
            print('No more directions. Halting')
            return

        if  direction == Direction.Down:
            x_shift, y_shift =  0,  1
        elif direction == Direction.Up:
            x_shift, y_shift =  0, -1
        elif direction == Direction.Left:
            x_shift, y_shift = -1,  0
        elif direction == Direction.Right:
            x_shift, y_shift =  1,  0

        new_cell = last_cell[0] + x_shift, last_cell[1] + y_shift
        self.route.append(new_cell)
        self.update_fitness()


    def cross_over(p1, p2, loc = None):
        # find the cross_over point
        if not loc:
            loc = randint(0,len(p1.directions))

        # choose one of the parents randomly
        x = randint(0,1)
        src_parent = (p1, p2)[x]
        dst_parent = (p1, p2)[1 - x]
        son = deepcopy(src_parent)
        son.directions[loc:] = deepcopy(dst_parent.directions[loc:])

        return son   

    def mutate(self, chance = 1):
        if 100*chance > randint(0,99):
            self.directions[len(self.route) - 1] = Direction(randint(0,3))




class GUI:
    def __init__(self, rows = 10, cols = 10, iteration_timer = 100, chromosomes = [], cross_over_chance = 0.5, mutation_chance = 0.3, MAX_ITER = 100):        

        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        self.canv_w = 800
        self.canv_h = 800
        self.cell_w = self.canv_w // cols
        self.cell_h = self.canv_h // rows

        self.master = tk.Tk()
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.master, width = self.canv_w, height = self.canv_h)       
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.rect_dict          = {}
        self.iteration_timer    = iteration_timer
        self.iterations         = 0
        self.MAX_ITER           = MAX_ITER

        self.chromosome_list = chromosomes
        self.src             = chromosomes[0].src # all chromosomes share src + dst
        self.dst             = chromosomes[0].dst

        self.prev_best_route    = []
        self.cross_over_chance  = cross_over_chance
        self.mutation_chance    = mutation_chance
        self.no_obstacles       = True

        # init grid #
        for r in range(rows):
            for c in range(cols):
                self.rect_dict[(r, c)] = self.canvas.create_rectangle(r    *self.cell_h, c    *self.cell_w,
                                                                      (1+r)*self.cell_h, (1+c)*self.cell_w,
                                                                      fill="gray")
        # init grid #

        # draw src + dst #
        self.color_src_dst()
        # draw src + dst #

        # after + mainloop #
        self.master.after(iteration_timer, self.start_gui)
        tk.mainloop()
        # after + mainloop #

    def start_gui(self):
        self.start_msg = self.canvas.create_text(self.canv_w // 2,3*self.canv_h // 4, fill = "black", font = "Times 25 bold underline", 
                                text="Starting new computation.\nPopulation size = %d\nCross-over chance = %.2f\nMutation chance = %.2f" %
                                (len(self.chromosome_list), self.cross_over_chance, self.mutation_chance))
        self.master.after(2000, self.update)

    def end_gui(self, msg="Bye Bye!"):
        self.master.wm_attributes('-alpha', 0.9) # transparency
        self.canvas.create_text(self.canv_w // 2,3*self.canv_h // 4, fill = "black", font = "Times 25 bold underline", text=msg)

        cell_ls = []
        for idx,cell in enumerate(self.prev_best_route):
            if cell in cell_ls:
                continue
            cell_ls.append(cell)
            self.canvas.create_text(cell[0]*self.cell_w, cell[1]*self.cell_h, fill = "purple", font = "Times 16 bold italic", text=str(idx+1))


        self.master.after(3000, self.master.destroy)

    def color_src_dst(self):
        r_src = self.rect_dict[self.src]
        r_dst = self.rect_dict[self.dst]
        c_src = 'blue'
        c_dst = 'red'
        self.canvas.itemconfig(r_src, fill=c_src)
        self.canvas.itemconfig(r_dst, fill=c_dst)

    def color_route(self, route, color):
        for cell in route:
            try:
                self.canvas.itemconfig(self.rect_dict[cell], fill=color)
            except KeyError:
                # out of bounds -> ignore
                continue

        # keep the src + dst
        self.color_src_dst()
        # keep the src + dst

    def compute_shortest_route(self):
        if self.no_obstacles:
            return (1 + 
                    abs(self.chromosome_list[0].dst[0] - self.chromosome_list[0].src[0]) + 
                    abs(self.chromosome_list[0].dst[1] - self.chromosome_list[0].src[1]))
        else:
            return 0

    def create_weighted_chromosome_list(self):
        ls = []
        for ch in self.chromosome_list:
            tmp = [ch] * (ch.fitness // 200000)
            ls.extend(tmp)
        return ls

    def cross_over(self):
        new_chromosome_ls = []
        weighted_ls = self.create_weighted_chromosome_list()

        while len(new_chromosome_ls) < len(self.chromosome_list):
            try:
                p1, p2 = sample(weighted_ls, 2)
                son = Chromosome.cross_over(p1, p2)
                if son in new_chromosome_ls:
                    continue
                else:
                    new_chromosome_ls.append(son)
            except ValueError:
                continue

        return new_chromosome_ls

    def end_successfully(self):
        self.end_gui(msg="Got to destination in %d iterations!\nBest route length = %d" % (len(self.prev_best_route), self.compute_shortest_route()))

    def update(self): 
        # first time #
        self.canvas.delete(self.start_msg)
        # first time #

        # end #
        if self.iterations >= self.MAX_ITER:
            self.end_gui()
            return
        # end #

        # clean the previously best chromosome route #
        self.color_route(self.prev_best_route[1:], 'gray')
        # clean the previously best chromosome route #

        # cross over #
        if 100*self.cross_over_chance > randint(0,99):
            self.chromosome_list = self.cross_over()
        # cross over #

        # update (includes mutations) all chromosomes #
        for ch in self.chromosome_list:
            ch.update(mutate_chance=self.mutation_chance)
        # update (includes mutations) all chromosomes #

        # show all chromsome fitness values #
        if debug_flag:
            fit_ls = [ch.fitness for ch in self.chromosome_list]
            print(self.iterations, sum(fit_ls) / len(fit_ls), fit_ls)
        # show all chromsome fitness values #

        # find and display best chromosome #
        best_ch = max(self.chromosome_list, key=lambda ch : ch.fitness)
        self.prev_best_route = deepcopy(best_ch.route)
        self.color_route(self.prev_best_route[1:], 'gold')
        # find and display best chromosome #

        # check if got to dst #
        if best_ch.dst == best_ch.route[-1]:
            self.end_successfully()
            return
        # check if got to dst #

        # after + update iterations #
        self.master.after(self.iteration_timer, self.update)
        self.iterations += 1
        # after + update iterations #



def main():
    iter_timer, ITER = 10, 350
    r,c              = 20,20
    s,d              = (13,11), (7,8)
    population_size     = [80,160]
    cross_over_chance   = [0.2,0.4,0.5]

    for pop_size, CO_chance in product(population_size, cross_over_chance):
        M_chance = 0.7 - CO_chance
        ch_ls = [Chromosome(src=s, dst=d, directions=[Direction(randint(0,3)) for i in range(ITER)]) for i in range(pop_size)]
        g = GUI(rows=r, cols=c, chromosomes = ch_ls, iteration_timer=iter_timer, 
                cross_over_chance=CO_chance, mutation_chance=M_chance, MAX_ITER=ITER-1)
        del(ch_ls)
        del(g)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if you know the [Python Profiling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/profiling-python-code-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) tool of Visual Studio, but it is quite useful in cases as yours (though I usually program with editors, like VS Code).

I have run your program and, as you said, it sometimes crashes. I have analyzed the code with the profiling tool and it seems that the problem is the function `cross_over`, specifically the random function:

[image]

[image]

I would strongly suggest reviewing your `cross_over` and `mutation` functions. The random function should not be called so many times (2 millions).

I have previously programmed Genetic Algorithms and, to me, it seems that your program is falling into a **local minimum**. What is suggested in these cases is **playing with the percentage of mutation**. Try to increase it a little bit so that you could get out of the local minimum.

Comment: I see. There is indeed a possible infinte loop there, that I noticed. Ill fix it and recheck. Thanks!!

Comment: The problem indeed lied there. I added a condition to stop the function calls after about ~1000 failures and it run smoothly

Comment: BTW, I played quite a lot with the mutation chance (up to 100%). Can't assure minimal route... not sure what's wrong. Most of my solutions are getting there in 14-16 steps instead 10.

Comment: The thing is that GAs do not guarantee always the optimal solution. But I guess you could get an "optimer" one depending on the fitness function.

Comment: I just expanded the population. Using population=1000, I get optimal result in about 50%, and the worst is always near-optimal

Comment: Great, I am glad you are obtaining good results. The drawback of increasing the population is that the program will go slower, but anyway GAs are not known for being the fastest algorithms. In the end, it is a trade-off between performance and optimal solution.